# MVC 5 with Fluent validation with two nullable datetimes ensuring end greater than start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

In an MVC 5 app I'm trying to compare two nullable date time with the code below.  It works fine however if I enter the same date for both start and end it is failing validation.   How can I amend this code so I can enter a start and end date both with the same date?

```
 RuleFor(m => m.StartDate)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Start Date is Required");

    RuleFor(m => m.EndDate)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
        .GreaterThan(m => m.StartDate.Value)
                        .WithMessage("End date must after Start date")
        .When(m => m.StartDate.HasValue);
```

Comment: `GreaterThanOrEqual(m => m.StartDate.Value)`?

Comment: Thanks that sorted it!